# Relationship of new Java 9 logging to existing logging APIs

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

Java logging seems to get murkier and murkier. I'm not going to go through the history, but the last I heard was that SLF4J was still the de-facto standard API for logging, even though Log4j now says it has a competing API.

As if that weren't enough, now in Java 9 there is some sort of new logging API.

- Does the new Java logging API supersede JUL?
- Is the new Java logging API meant to replace SLF4j?
- What is the latest de-facto standard logging API for Java as of 2019?

Comment: Do you have a link to what you mean by the new logging API in Java 9?

Comment: Well, when I enter "new logging api Java 9" in Google Search, the first link it gives me is https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-logging-api , which begins with, "… we’ll explore the newly introduced Logging API in Java 9 …". That is only one site of many, as well as many Java 9+ books that mention it (e.g. _Java 9 Revealed_ by Apress, Chapter 19).

Comment: I'd completely missed this. From looking at JEP-264 it seems that the intention isn't to replace SLF4J. It looks like the idea is to allow SDK level logging to be unified with application level logging by splitting the interface from the implementation.